# Use request / user in django admin template

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.6

I'm trying to access the user / request variables in django admin templates.

Specifically, I'd like to add new submit buttons depending on the user role. I've copied submit_line.html in my project template folder, but calling {{user}} or {{request}} don't display anything.

I've already added the following in my settings file.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",  
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Did I miss something?

Alternatively, is there a standard way to add submit buttons besides editing submit_line.html?

Comment: Exactly where have you put the overridden template? Do you see any other changes you make to it?

Comment: It' in templates/admin, and I can see other changes I've made here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the code for the `submit_row` templatetag (the one that renders `submit_line.html`), you'll notice that the original context is not passed to the `submit_line.html` template.

I'm afraid your best bet will be to replace the `submit_row` templatetag with something of your own, and override the `admin/change_form.html` template to call your own templatetag instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine by creating my_submit_row as a copy of the original submit_row, adding ctx['user'] = context['user'] in order to pass it to the template